# How do I bind data to an html object conditioned on whether the html dataset and object key values are matching using javascript?

Tags: javascript, json, for-loop, topojson

I am trying to bind data to an svg map.

However, there are some inconsistencies between the TopoJSON file I used to create the map and the data. The biggest hurdle is that some of the properties values in the TopoJSON file (in my case, the ZIP codes) repeat. This makes the array lengths different, and thus makes using a simple for loop impossible.

Here's an example.

Let's say this is the rendered SVG map with some key values I pulled from TopoJSON file and added to the paths as a dataset:

```
<svg>
    <path data-key="1"></path>
    <path data-key="2"></path>
    <path data-key="2"></path>
    <path data-key="2"></path>
    <path data-key="3"></path>
    <path data-key="3"></path>
    <path data-key="4"></path>
    <path data-key="5"></path>
    <path data-key="6"></path>
    <path data-key="8"></path>
</svg>
```

Here is an example of the data object that comes from a different source:

```
const data = [
    {
        key: 2,
        value: 30
    },
    {
        key: 4,
        value: 50
    },
    {
        key: 8,
        value: 75
    }
]
```

I want to add the object values as a dataset entry to each path but only to paths that have a dataset entry that matches the object key.

Here's the result I am looking for:

```
<svg>
    <path data-key="1"></path>
    <path data-key="2" data-value:"30"></path>
    <path data-key="2" data-value:"30"></path>
    <path data-key="2" data-value:"30"></path>
    <path data-key="3"></path>
    <path data-key="3"></path>
    <path data-key="4" data-value:"50"></path>
    <path data-key="5"></path>
    <path data-key="6"></path>
    <path data-key="8" data-value="75"></path>
</svg>
```

Because the node list for the paths and the object are two different lengths, running a simple for loop doesn't seem to be working. I also tried a while condition in my for loop, but that didn't work either.

I also researched if this was possible using mapping or filter. However, I am not trying to make a new array, so these didn't seem like viable options.

Is there a way to accomplish this? Or perhaps it is easier to add my data object to my original topoJSON as part of its properties list?

Thanks, in advance, for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this (written in vanilla JS):

```
data.forEach(item => {
   const paths = document.querySelectorAll(`path[data-key="${item.key}"]`);
   [].forEach.call(paths, function(path) {
     path.dataset['value'] = item.value
   });
})
```